# use variable as a table name in INSERT TO

Tags: php, mysql

hello i am going to insert some data into data base.
There are no my sql error but data not inserted into data base. My code is:

```
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
  mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");


if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){ 
$category= $_POST['category'];

if ($category==1) {$cat="rf_power";
$sub_cat=$_POST['power']; $dur="p_duration";}
if ($category==2) {$cat="rf_bts";
$sub_cat=$_POST['BTS']; $dur="b_duration";}
 if ($category==3) {$cat="rf_transmission";
 $sub_cat=$_POST['transmission']; $dur="t_duration";}
 if ($category==4) {$cat="core_network";$sub_cat=$_POST['core']; $dur="duration";}
 if ($category==5) {$cat="daisy_chain";
 $sub_cat=$_POST['daisy']; $dur="d_duration";}

 $dateid=date('Y-m-d');
 $s_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['s_name']);
 $location=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
 $alarm_type=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a_type']);
 $severity=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['severity']);
 $reason=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reason']);
 $shift_operation=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shto_do']);
 $system_operation=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['syto_do']);
 $start_time=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date1']);
 $end_time=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date2']);
 $dur=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date3']);
 echo $dateid;
 echo $s_name;
 echo $sub_cat;
 echo $location;
 echo $alarm_type;
 echo $severity;
 echo $start_time;
 echo $end_time;
 echo $dur;
 echo $reason;
 echo $shift_operation;
 echo $system_operation;
 echo $cat ;

  $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$cat." (dateid,system_name,sub_cat,location,alarmtype,severity,start_time,end_time,duartion,reason,shift_operation,system_operation)
    VALUES ('$dateid','$s_name','$sub_cat','$location','$alarm_type','$severity','$start_time','$end_time','$dur','$reason','$shift_operation','$system_operation')";
 }
```

all prints normal by echo. i think the error is for the "INSERT INTO ".$cat." . $cat is right in here?

Comment: You have not _executed_ your query, at least not in the posted code.

Comment: You should try to stop using the PHP mysql API http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the posted code it seems your query is not being executed, but stored inside `$sql` and sitting there.. From the code there is nothing to actually execute the query, I have added this in the bottom. the addition of `mysql_query($sql);` Will run the script against your selected database

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $cat (dateid,system_name,sub_cat,location,alarmtype,severity,start_time,end_time,duartion,reason,shift_operation,system_operation)
        VALUES ('$dateid','$s_name','$sub_cat','$location','$alarm_type','$severity','$start_time','$end_time','$dur','$reason','$shift_operation','$system_operation')";
    mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: i hope there is no error until $sql = "INSERT INTO because there all data prints normal by echo. I have tried  $sql = "INSERT INTO $cat this also but it was same

Comment: @ganaa I have added an extra line `mysql_query($sql);`